# An integral of composite function of triangle functions

Tags: integration

I expected the following formula to hold:

$\int^{2n\pi}_0\cos(\sin t+t/n)dt=0$,
for ${}^\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\ n\geq2$

But I can't prove it.
Could you please tell me.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why people are voting to close this. Is it a well-known result? Is it obvious? I think the poster is saying that he found that this seems to be true numerically, and is asking for a proof or reference. I checked it numerically up to $n=10$.

Comment: I voted to close because I would have expected an explanation of why it might be expected to hold. More generally the question lacks context. Also it's evidently true for even $n$ by comparing $t$ and $t+n\pi$.

Comment: This is a question for MSE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite the integral as
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\cos\Big(\sin t+\tfrac tn+2\pi \tfrac jn\Big)\right)\,dt.
$$
But $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\cos\big(a+2\pi \tfrac jn\big)=0$ for all $a$.

In particular, the equality holds if $\sin t$ is replaced by *any* $2\pi$-periodic function.

Comment: Nice. And for $n=1$ you sum is $\cos(a)$, not 0, which explains why the integral is non-zero for $n=1$. I guess there will be a difference of opinion as to whether this belongs on MO or MSE, but I will say it's a clever trick that I enjoyed seeing.

Comment: Thank you very much.
You are smart.